# how to override the `to` field of a contract deployment init transaction?

Tags: transactions, hardhat, ethers.js, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to deploy a contract using [Deterministic Deployment Proxy](https://github.com/Zoltu/deterministic-deployment-proxy) to a deterministic address. Since all the network has the deployer proxy deployed to it at address `0x7A0D94F55792C434d74a40883C6ed8545E406D12`. In order to deploy a `MY_CONTRACT` I want to change `to` address from `null` to `proxy_address` on the outbound contract deployment transaction using hardhat, ethers or other helper tools?

That is how to overrides the `to` field of a contract deployment transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that uses [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org), [Ethers](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js) and [TypeChain](https://github.com/ethereum-ts/TypeChain):

```
import { TransactionRequest, TransactionResponse } from "@ethersproject/abstract-provider";
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { task } from "hardhat/config";

import { PRBProxy__factory } from "../../typechain/factories/PRBProxy__factory";

const DETERMINISTIC_DEPLOYMENT_PROXY_ADDRESS: string = "0x7A0D94F55792C434d74a40883C6ed8545E406D12";

task("deploy:contract:prb-proxy").setAction(async function (_, { ethers }): Promise<void> {
  const signers: SignerWithAddress[] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const deployer: SignerWithAddress = signers[0];

  const prbProxyFactory: PRBProxy__factory = new PRBProxy__factory(deployer);
  const deploymentTx: TransactionRequest = prbProxyFactory.getDeployTransaction();
  deploymentTx.to = DETERMINISTIC_DEPLOYMENT_PROXY_ADDRESS;
  const txResponse: TransactionResponse = await deployer.sendTransaction(deploymentTx);
  await txResponse.wait();
});
```

You can replace `PRBProxy__factory` with your own contract factory.

Answer (score 1):

We simply do something like:
`factory.getDeployTransaction(args)` to generate the tx, and then add the `to` and use `signer.sendTransaction(tx)`.